Variation in treatment condition in regression discontinuity model
I have a conceptual question regarding the implementation of a regression discontinuity model. I am working on a paper examining the effect of a policy that allows for program funding if a geographic area is within a state-based coastal area; however, the exact area that is included within a state-based coastal area varies by state. That is, the distance from the coast varies by state but it tends to be within 1-3 miles. My thought was that the control group would be those areas that are within 1, 2, or 3 miles of the border of the state-based coastal area. My question is two-fold. First, does it matter that the exact area where treatment occurs varies by state? Second, if I am interested in whether a policy is adopted as the outcome (e.g. binary outcome), is that feasible in a regression discontinuity framework?
